# Created 1.2GB PI partition, but WinImage makes a 5.2GB image when I backup

Tags: raspbian-jessie, backup

I created a PI system that I want to copy to 20 or so other PI SD cards.  The partition is only 1.2 GB (A Jessie image).  I then use WinImage to create a vhd file using the "Create Dynamically Expanding Virtual Hard Disk" option.  That option means that if the SD card is 8GB and your only using 1GB, then the resulting image is 1GB.  But I'm getting , but it results in a 5.2GB image file.

```
root@rpi-scale-baseimage:/home/bi-user# parted -l
Model: SD SD8GB (sd/mmc)
Disk /dev/mmcblk0: 7860MB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags:

Number  Start   End     Size    Type     File system  Flags
 1      4194kB  67.1MB  62.9MB  primary  fat16        lba
 2      67.1MB  1361MB  1294MB  primary  ext4
```

and...

```
root@rpi-scale-baseimage:/home/bi-user# df
Filesystem     1K-blocks   Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/root        1210960 919868    211528  82% /
devtmpfs          469688      0    469688   0% /dev
tmpfs             474008      0    474008   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs             474008   6324    467684   2% /run
tmpfs               5120      4      5116   1% /run/lock
tmpfs             474008      0    474008   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/mmcblk0p1     61384  20368     41016  34% /boot
root@rpi-scale-baseimage:/home/bi-user#
```

Comment: This seems to be a question about Windows or a Windows program.

Comment: Hmm, I hadn't even considered that.  I was thinking this was more about the fact that the image was a PI image, that perhaps it was putting data on the SSD oddly or something.  But your point is a good one, it could be WinImage.  I've used it for years outside of the PI realm without anything like this happening though.  Thank you for the insight!